# c# Set Parent class property in child setter

Tags: c#

Im trying to set a parent class property in child property setter.
I have one main class :**User**, which has a child class LIST **ArrayPositions**, which in turn has a child class list of **ExpressionMember**.
Whenever the property **ExpressionMemValue** in ExpressionMember class is set, i want to update it's parent class ArrayPosition aswell. 
However the current solution does not update the corresponding parent.
Here's the code:

```
   public List<User> users = new List<User>();
    public class User 
    {
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        private string _PartName = "";
        public string PartName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._PartName; 
            }
            set { 
                _PartName=value; 
            }
        }
        public List <ArrayPosition> ArrayPositions { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.PartName.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class ArrayPosition:User 
    {
        public string myArrayPos = "";
        public string PartId { get; set; }
        public string ArrayPos
        {
            get
            {              
                return this.myArrayPos;                 
            }
            set
            {
                this.myArrayPos = value;
            }

        }
        public List<ExpressionMember> ExpressionMembers { get; set; }
    }        
    public class ExpressionMember : ArrayPosition
    {
        public string ExpressionMem { get; set; }
        public string MyExpressionMemValye="";            
        public string ExpressionMemValue
        {
            get
            {
                return MyExpressionMemValye;                
            }
            set
            {                   
                MyExpressionMemValye = value;
               // this.ArrayPos = value;  //set parent value, this will not update it                           
            }

        }          
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps your issue here is that you are *using* inheritance but *saying* composition. Your code is indeed setting the base member, but given how you are describing it, you may be expecting the incorrect behavior based on how you wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However i did not quite understand what you were saying. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @Raunts You are confusing inheritance (ancestor–descendant class relationships) with run-time parent–child instance relatioships. This is quite clear to guess from the *absolutely weird* inheritance hierarchy in the code sample.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. How should i build up the class inside class relation? - I must have the child classes as List inside the parent class. And also make the child -> parent update work ( the main question of the topic).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  If you create an instance of ExpressionMember then ArrayPos will be set in the property setter ExpressionMemValue. See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCm5q3

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you need to not use inheritance and instead use composition which you are kind of already doing. Try doing this instead. It's not perfect by any means but I'm trying not to change your general strategy too much.

```
public class User 
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    private string _PartName = "";
    public string PartName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._PartName; 
        }
        set { 
            _PartName=value; 
        }
    }
    public List <ArrayPosition> ArrayPositions { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.PartName.ToString();
    }
}
public class ArrayPosition 
{
    public string myArrayPos = "";
    public string PartId { get; set; }
    public string ArrayPos
    {
        get
        {              
            return this.myArrayPos;                 
        }
        set
        {
            this.myArrayPos = value;
        }

    }

    public List<ExpressionMember> ExpressionMembers { get; set; }
}        
public class ExpressionMember
{
    private ArrayPosition _parentArrayPosition;
    public string ExpressionMem { get; set; }
    public string MyExpressionMemValye="";            
    public string ExpressionMemValue
    {
        get
        {
            return MyExpressionMemValye;                
        }
        set
        {                   
            MyExpressionMemValye = value;
            this._parentArrayPosition.ArrayPos = value;
        }

        public ExpressionMember(ArrayPosition parent) {
            _parentArrayPosition = parent;
        }
    }          
}
```

You are definitely not using inheritance and composition correctly. You are looking to build a tree of objects where the object itself has child objects. Something that might clarify things in your mind is instead of calling them child/parent classes, refer to them as sub/super classes in the case of inheritance and parent/child objects in the case of composition. A parent object is an instance of a class that contains another instance of a class (child object). A subclass inherits the members of another class.

Comment: beat me too it.  Was going to post exact replica of this (without the properties you are not needing for demonstrating what you need to do.  Although I had a Main in my updated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/UCm5q3

Comment: @Andez Hah, nice fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your inheritance is very strange. The exact responsibilities of your classes are not clear to me.
Apart from that, you could protect the property `ExpressionMembers` by making it read-only. Implement a new method to add or remove elements. Add an event (e.g. `ExpressionMemValueChanged`) to `ExpressionMember` . This event is triggered when an item is added. Whenever an element is added or removed you register/deregister `ArrayPosition` to/from this event. Inside the event handler you can then set your `ArrayPos` value.

(You can use an `ObservableCollection` for your `ExpressionMembers` and react to the `CollectionChanged` event instead of writing a getter/setter.)